# Access file from another package

Tags: java, package, inputstreamreader

My situation is as following : I have package `packA` where I have `classA`, and I have a `file.txt` in `packB.resources`. In `classA` I'm using this to access `file.txt` :

```
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/packB/resources/file.txt"), "UTF-8");
```

But unfortunately it shows me an exception :

> java.io.FileNotFoundException : \packB\resources\file.txt (The
>   specified path was not found)

Comment: The code and the error message do not match. The code uses `"resources"` but the error message says `"ressources"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FileInputStream class opens a file in the file system based on a file system path.

But what you are apparently trying to do is to open a resource located via the classpath.  You should be using `Class.getResourceAsStream(String)`.

Answer (score 2):

If your `file.txt` is packaged with application you should not access using file system at all. The application may be packaged into jar, so the file is not located in file system. You should access it as a resource instead:

```
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/packB/resources/file.txt"), "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like the following.  Note, the / used as a prefix before the package name.  YourClass is assumed to be in packA.

```
InputStream stream = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/packB/resources/file.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the trailing `/` from the file path and use `classA.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("packB/resources/file.txt")`.